# SNS not triggering Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I created a Lambda function to perform a curl function to send a message to a slack webhook. If I test it in the Lambda CLI it works as it should. I linked an SNS trigger to it and it never runs the Lambda function. I have read posts with similar issues and they mostly lead to trigger permissions. I think mine are OK since you can see that the SNS trigger is set in the Lambda function.

To test the SNS trigger I also added a subscription to it to send me an email. When I test the SNS using "Publish message" I do get an email yet the Lambda does not get triggered. What am I missing????

As you can see here the SNS trigger is added for the Lambda function:
Is there anything else that needs to be added?

Lambda dashboard - 
[image]

SNS dashboard -
[image]

Lambda code - which works fine when I run the test button in the CLI

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    import subprocess

    # Send message to slack
    message = event['text']
    data = json.dumps({'text': 'test message'})
    subprocess.call([
        'curl',
        '-X', 'POST',
        '-H', 'Content-type: application/json',
        '--data', data,          'https://hooks.slack.com/services/T0xxxxxxxx/BLxxxxxxx/ysSl5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    ])
```

The Function Policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "sns-us-east-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-Ernie_dev-CodeDeploy-Successful",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:invokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-xxxxxxxxxxxxx:function:Slack-CodeDeploy_ernie-dev_success",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-xxxxxxxxxxxxx:Ernie_dev-CodeDeploy-Successful"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```